# How to use glDrawArrays() with VBO - Vertex Buffer Object to display .stl geometry

Tags: python, opengl, pyopengl

I am working in Python with PyOpenGL bindings for OpenGL. I have a geometry data in .stl file and I read the file and create a data `vertices` that has the form:

```
vertices = [ -0.8528478   4.046846   -1.,..,  -1.441251   -1.07833    10.85     ]
```

or:

```
vertices = [[ -0.8528478   4.046846   -1.       ]
            [  5.244714    7.080829   -1.       ]
             ..., 
            [ -1.596363   -0.8316395  10.85     ]
            [ -1.441251   -1.07833    10.85     ]]
```

the data is the same in both cases, the difference is only in shape. I create the VBO with method `geometry()` from .stl file using `model_loader`:

```
def geometry(self):
    glEnable(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)
    #    generate a new VBO and get the associated vbo_id
    id = 1
    #    bind VBO in order to use
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.vbo_id)
    #    upload data to VBO
    vertices = model_loader.Model_loader(filename = "body.stl").vertices
    self.N_vertices = len(vertices)
    #    data size in bytes
    dataSize = arrays.ArrayDatatype.arrayByteCount(vertices)
    print "dataSize =", dataSize
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, dataSize, vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW)
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.vbo_id)
```

Drawing is done in method `paintGL`:

```
def paintGL(self):
    """
    display geometry
    """
    # Clear the screen
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
    #    setup camera
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
    glLoadMatrixf(self.camera.currentMatrix)
    glPushMatrix()      #we don't want each object to move the camera           
    glTranslatef(-10, 0, 0)
    #     light
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, np.array([0.0, 100.0, -100.0]))
    glLightModeli( GL_LIGHT_MODEL_TWO_SIDE, GL_TRUE )
    glColor4f(1, 1, 1, 1)
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)
    glVertexPointer(3, 
                    GL_FLOAT, 
                    0, 
                    0)
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.vbo_id)   
    glDrawArrays( GL_TRIANGLES, 
                  0, 
                  self.N_vertices )
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,0) # reset
    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)
    glPopMatrix()
```

The problem is, that it only displays one point if I change to `GL_POINTS` and when `GL_TRANGLES` is used is doesn't display anything!

Before working with VBO I display the geometry only with the `glDrawArrays()` and the geometry was/is displayed without problems (no errors). But when trying to implement VBO it is not working. How can it be solved?

Comment: For future reference, avoid the `STL` tag. That is for the C++ Standard Template Library. This question is related to a CAD file format, which unfortunately does not have its own tag.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman
Thanks for the comment about the meaning of .STL (I did not know that). This question is about VBO in OpenGL as there is some error when creating or drawing VBO (not displaying anything). Do you know if one can check if the created VBO has data and print the data of VBO?

Comment: You can map/unmap a VBO to memory and read from that, or you can call `glGetBufferSubData (...)` to read-back values from the VBO. In all honesty, I think the order you are calling `glBindBufer (...)` in is to blame. You have a few redundant binds and a few late ones - `glVertexPointer (...)` needs to come ***after*** you bind the buffer, because the address you pass is an offset into the memory of whatever VBO was current when you made the call. The way GL uses "current" state is annoying at times, D3D is much simpler since each command includes the object(s) they are relative to in the call.

Comment: Thanks for the comments @AndonM.Coleman. About `glGetBufferSubData()` what should be the last parameter **data**, does it has to be predefined (using Python)?
You suggest to position `glVertexPointer()` after the `glDrawArrays()` in the method `paintGL`?
I would just like to inform you that I have fixed the problem. But I would still like if you could give me explanation about the above 2 questions.

Comment: No, `glVertexPointer (...)` should come first. As for **data**, this is a pointer to the vertex data. In the old days it used to be a pointer to regular memory, but in modern OpenGL it is actually an *offset* into your VBO's memory. Thus, **0** is actually a valid data pointer when you are using VBOs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem. If anyone else will have similar problem, here is the solution. As I am using 64-bit version of python (including numpy). The `vertices` are type numpy.array() and were type (dtype) `float64`.

I changed the line in the model loader from:

```
self.vertices =  np.array(self.vertices)
```

to:

```
self.vertices =  np.array(self.vertices, dtype='float32')
```

Based on that I would say that (older) GPU only support float32. Or do GPUs support float64? If anyone can clarify this it would be great.

Comment: Your numpy type must correlate with the your glVertexPointer call.  GL_FLOAT for 32-bit and GL_DOUBLE for 64-bit.  However, you are correct in assuming that many graphics cards do not support 64-bit.